# Moving Row/Column Groups and Placing Adjacent Row Groups on Same Row

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I am working on the following report and need some help configuring groups.

[image: This is what I have so far.]

I am trying to achieve two things:

1. I want to add an adjacent row group (for *CollateralType*) to *PortfolioGroupName* in the cell where *CollateralType* is. However, whenever I right click on the *PortfolioGroupName* to add an adjacent group, my only options are to add an adjacent row above or below. How can I add the adjacent row group to be on the same row as *PortfolioGroupName*?
2. I also need the *Role* column group to encompass the entire table (minus the *EmpName* column). Currently the group lies over the  cell, but I can neither move it nor delete it and get the group to encompass the whole table. How can I fix this grouping?

Comment: It sounds like your goal is to have two separate row groups in the same row, is that correct?  If so, this will not be possible.  Unless I'm mistaken, row groups should always correspond to the entire row. One possible alternative that would require a bit of extra work -- put a list item down and build separate tables for each row group -- just align them identically.  Perhaps you could add columns for `EmpName`, `Loan Count`, `Collateral Count`, and the `Role` column group and just nest a tablix in each column with a single row grouped by `EmpName`.

Answer (score 0):

1. An adjacent row group in the same row would need to be either a child group or a parent group, the options to add these will be showing.
2. You will need to copy the contents of and delete the columns to the left of the Role column group, insert columns in the role group and add the contents back with paste if possible or manually.